# angular2 router.navigate inside auth0 callback

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, auth0

I am having an issue rendering a template after calling router.navigate inside a callback for auth0lock

loginComponent.ts

```
import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

import {Auth} from '../auth';

declare var Auth0Lock;

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: '/tpls/login/login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {

    private lock = new Auth0Lock('xxx', 'xxx.auth0.com');

    constructor(@Inject(Router) private router: Router, @Inject(Auth) private auth: Auth) { }

    logError = (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }

    loginSuccess = (data) => {
        if(this.router.parent.lastNavigationAttempt !== undefined && this.router.parent.lastNavigationAttempt !== '/Login') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.parent.lastNavigationAttempt);
        } else if(data.user.req_update) {
            this.router.navigate(['Profile']);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['Home']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.lock.show((err: Error, profile: any, id_token: string) => {
            if(err) return this.logError(err);
            return this.auth.login(profile, id_token);
        }); 

        this.auth.loginSuccess.subscribe(
            data => this.loginSuccess(data),
            err => this.logError(err)
        );

    }
}
```

auth.ts

```
import {Injectable, Inject, EventEmitter, Output } from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()

export class Auth {
    ...
    @Output() loginSuccess = new EventEmitter();

    login = (profile, id_token) => {
        ...

        this.addUser(profile).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.loginSuccess.next(data.json());
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err); 
                this.loginSuccess.error(err.json());
            }
        );
    }
    addUser = (user: any) => {
        let body = JSON.stringify(user);
        return this.http.post('/api/user/add', body, { headers: this.headers});
    }
}
```

homeComponent.ts

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router'

import {Auth} from '../auth';
import {Post} from '../post/Post';
import {IPost} from '../post/IPost';
import {AuthorComponent} from '../author/authorComponent';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: '/tpls/home/home.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, AuthorComponent]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    private postService: Post;
    private posts: IPost[];

    constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http, @Inject(Auth) private auth: Auth) {
        console.log('constructor');
        this.postService = new Post(this.http, this.auth);
        this.getPosts();
    }

    getPosts = () => {
        this.postService.all().subscribe(
            data => this.getPostsCallback(data.json()),
            err => this.logError(err)
        );
    }

    getPostsCallback = (data) => {
        console.log('callback');
        this.posts = data;
    }

    logError = (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('init');
        //this.postService = new Post(this.http, this.auth);
        //this.getPosts();
    }

}
```

I am including the cdn script for authlock in my index page. Seems like any route I navigate to after login does not render. The callback from this.lock.show works and I can read the variables. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

basic concept: https://plnkr.co/edit/Oz8lY7v6q8GpH71WLtAK

Comment: I two have had issues using router.navigate and router.navigateByUrl from any asynchronous type code. If the call to the router is in promise, callback, or observable it always seems to fail.  I've tried things like using NgZone etc, but the only thing that I've gotten to work consistently is to put the navigate outside of any of the async code. I'd love to find a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Should fix your problem.

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public router: Router, public _zone: NgZone) {}
```

then inside your callback , call this

```
this._zone.run(()=>{
  this.router.navigate(['uploader']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this auth0 article](https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-angular-2-change-detection/) I found a solution to the problem, since `NgZone` wasn't working for me.

Wrapping the request in `bindNodeCallback` did the trick. 
This function wraps the Auth0 request with Zone.js and thus doing the request in the Angular zone.

My code was:

```
this._auth0.parseHash((err, authResult: auth0.Auth0DecodedHash) => {
    if (!err && authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
       window.location.hash = ''; // Remove the Auth0 trailing hash
    }

    this.ngZone.run(() => {
       this.router.navigate(['<some-url>']);
    });
});
```

But that resulted in not navigating to any page due to being out of Angular scope. I replaced that code with a Zone.js wrapped version to make it work:

```
this.parseHash$ = bindNodeCallback(this._auth0.parseHash.bind(this._auth0));
this.parseHash$().subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['<some-url>']));
```

And editing the request result can be done in the `subscribe` or via the `map` functions.

---

**Versions**

For the code above I am using the following versions:

**Angular** `6.1.7`

**auth0-js** `9.8.0`

Comment: This seems like really an obscure solution.   I don't see how the call to ngZone.run is "out of scope" if it actually has access to this this.router property.

Comment: Hey, I'm having this exact same issue... trying to follow your eventual solution but it's not clear to me where the callback code goes. I can confirm that the NgZone solution doesn't work.

Can you post the full code of your solutions?

Comment: Hi @user1543276, I am no longer working on the project so I cannot post the exact code, but you can find the example code I followed here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login#finish-the-service