# Template HTML not loading after authentication Auth0

Tags: angular, jwt, angular2-routing, auth0

I'm following Auth0 login sample given here https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs2-systemjs-sample/tree/master/01-Login .

Here is my auth service code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { myConfig } from '../auth0.config';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.ClientID,myConfig.DomainName, {
     auth: {
       redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/server-auth',
       responseType: 'token',
       params: {
         state: 'mologin'
       }
     }
  });

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
      this.router.navigate(['/emails'])
    });

  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  };

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // It searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired();
  };

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  };
}
```

On successful routing I'm navigating to my emails page. The email component gets loaded. Its constructor and onInit methods are called successfully. But the html doesn't gets displayed.

Here's my authentication guard code. The user doesn't gets routed to login page so that's fine.

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import { Auth } from '../../services';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: Auth, private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        let url = route.url[0];
        if (!this.authService.authenticated()) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here's the email component which is loading after successful navigation.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'email-templates',
    templateUrl: './email-templates.component.html'
})
export class EmailTemplatesComponent implements OnInit {

    public isLoaded: Boolean = false;
    public barData:any;//barChart data
    private emailsArray: Array<any> = [];//table's data

    constructor(private router: Router, private toasterService: ToasterService,
        private elementRef: ElementRef, private emailService: EmailTemplateService,
        public modal: Modal, public overlay: Overlay, public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {
         overlay.defaultViewContainer = vcRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getAllEmails();

    }

    getAllEmails() {
        this.emailService.getAllEmails().subscribe(res => {
            if(res.success=="true"){
            this.emailsArray = res.data;
           }
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided it's difficult to provide you a definitive answer, but it's likely that the following is occurring:

1. Your server-side is requiring authentication for serving static file like the Angular2 HTML templates.
2. You navigate to the emails page and the template request fails due to lack of proper authentication.

If this is the case, you can confirm by looking into the network trace through the browser developer tools, you need to allow the HTML templates to be obtained without requiring authentication.

Additionally, using a `setTimeout` to save the ID Token in Web storage is not something you see everyday so you may want to explain your use case with a bit of more details.

Comment: setTimeout I used used just for a little delay in routing. I have edited it in question.

Comment: The authentication is correct as I use authenticated() method in service to confirm the authentication on every route. I don't think so the server side requires authentication for serving files, as if after authentication when blank email page comes and I refresh the browser, then the page gets loaded fine with all the Api hits successful.

Comment: My questions is almost similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068366/angular2-router-navigate-inside-auth0-callback . But it hasn't been answered too

Comment: When you refresh after authentication, any requests that require authentication would in theory work; that's the reason why them not working before authentication would lead me to suggest that the template was requiring authentication on the server-side. Did you use the browser tools to get more information about the HTTP response for the HTML template? Can you include that information in the question?

Comment: The http get request in my email component returns success:"true" response. There is no other http request to server in my component. The html on angular 2 is on front end it doesn't get received in response. The only response I'm getting from server is the data in json format which I am receiving as desired.  Response is as follows { timestampt:'timestamp', success:'true', data:[returned data] }

Comment: Okay, cool, if the templates are not served as separate files this rules out any authentication issues on the server. If you also don't get any errors in the console, then instrument your code (using `console.log`)  and try to pinpoint if anything that you would expect to happen does not happen or happens differently. For example, your client-side code may be failing to recognize that the user is already authenticated. Additionally, include more info about routing, activation guards and email component code in the question as it may help to troubleshoot.

Comment: I've added email component and activation guard's code. The authentication gets successful. I've consoled it and it works fine. Moreover the getAllEmails() function also successfully gets the response from API. Even if on my html page, I give static html that too doesnt gets rendered.